# Associated primes and principal ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be any commutative ring, and let $a \in A$ be a nonzerodivisor.
How do I show that the associated primes of $A/(a)$ are exactly the associated primes for $A/(a^n)$, where $n \geq 1$ is any integer?

One inclusion seems fine, namely that if $\mathfrak{p}$ is an associated prime of $A/(a)$, $\mathfrak{p} =$ Ann($x$) for some $x \in A/(a)$. Then $x\mathfrak{p} \subseteq (a)$, so that $a^{n-1}x\mathfrak{p} \subseteq (a^n)$ for any $n$ and so $\mathfrak{p}$ is associated to $A/(a^n)$. However, I don't know how to do the converse at all - any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: An inductive argument using the following exact sequence might work here:
$$0\to\frac{a^nA}{a^{n+1}A}\to \frac{A}{a^{n+1}A}\to \frac{A}{a^{n}A}\to 0.$$

Note also that $$\frac{a^nA}{a^{n+1}A}\cong \frac{A}{aA}.$$

Comment: One final hint: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02M3.